# Leafs turning yellow and fall off rubber fig

Tags: plant-care

What is happening to my rubber fig? Rather many leafs are now turning yellow and  falling off? I got this large plant last autumn and it now the end of the Winter season (here in Central Europe). One branch seems mainly affected, but it is not the only one. I'm watering it approx. every other week, and it's situated in a living room with normal room temperatures.

Can somebody perhaps please diagnose the situation and indicate how such a plant (rubber fig a bit more than 2 meters in height) should be cared for in general.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can we have  another  photo of the whole plant and its pot please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can happen in winter when there’s not enough sun indoors.
When there’ll be more sun, just prune the tree and new leaves will grow.

You can also think of getting it more light next winter (closer to southern windows, additional lamps, etc.)

Also, check the leaf undersides for bugs (just in case).